# Serial Comm shared library sending wrong data when used with ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a built a simple serial communication shared library which I am trying to use in python using the ctypes library. The steps that I am following are:

1. Load the .so file by calling ctypes.cdll.loadlibrary().
2. Initialize the serial communication module.
3. Send 0xFF as sync bytes.

When I do the above steps I am not getting only junk data at the other end. Funnily when I use the .so file in C and do the same operation it works absolutely fine. So My question is does the ctypes module manipulate the loaded library in any way? I am quite new to using C in Python and I am drawing blank here. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes
test_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./demo_static.so")
string2 = "/dev/ttyS2"
# create byte objects from the strings
UART_RIGHT = string2.encode('utf-8')
baud = 500000
test_lib.serial_com_init(0, UART_RIGHT, baud)
```

The (relevant) C code:

```
int serial_com_init(char *left, char *right, int baudrate) {
    int fd_l, fd_r;
    uart_t uart_left, uart_right;
    uint8_t flags_l, flags_r;
    if (left) {
        fd_l = uart_init_linux(left, baudrate);
        uart_left->fd = fd_l;
    }
    if (right) {
        fd_r = uart_init_linux(right, baudrate);
        uart_right->fd = fd_r;
    }
    serial_com_init_cr(uart_left, uart_right, flags_l, flags_r); 
    serial_com_hello_init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes

test_lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./demo_static.so")

string2 = "/dev/ttyS2""

# create byte objects from the strings
UART_RIGHT = string2.encode('utf-8')

baud = 500000

test_lib.serial_com_init(0,UART_RIGHT,baud)`

Comment: There's no code that actually sends data. What lib are you using? Does `serial_com_init` return something? Could you also post the (*C*) working code?

Comment: The serial_com_init function initializes the the serial com with the correct baud and then sends 0xFF as a hello ping which if sent correctly i can see it on the console. But it is sending junk value for some reason.`int serial_com_init(char* left,char* right,int baudrate){
 int fd_l,fd_r;uart_t uart_left,uart_right;uint8_t flags_l,flags_r;
 if (left){
fd_l=uart_init_linux(left, baudrate);
uart_left->fd = fd_l;
}
if (right){
fd_r=uart_init_linux(right, baudrate);
uart_right->fd=fd_r;
}
serial_com_init_cr(uart_left,uart_right,flags_l,flags_r);
serial_com_hello_init();
return 0;}`

Comment: @sandeepmanjunath22 Don't post code in comments.  Edit your question with the requested information and format it correctly.

Comment: Sure.. I will do that..Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value)

Answer (score 0):

According to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Specifying the required argument types (function prototypes)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes), for a function like:

```c
int serial_com_init(char *left, char *right, int baudrate);
```

you need to specify argument types (**before** the function call). This makes a crucial difference on *064bit* *Python*. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for more details:

```py
test_lib.serial_com_init.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int)
test_lib.serial_com_init.restype = ctypes.c_int
init_result = test_lib.serial_com_init(None, UART_RIGHT, baud)
```

**Notes**:

- This is one of the possible causes
- **Always** check functions return codes (well, here it will always be ***0***, and this might hide errors in the *C* code)
- You can use *bytes* literals directly: `UART_RIGHT = b"/dev/ttyS2"`

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. Although i have a different problem with my serial com module now, this worked. It initialized the serial Comm..So i have something to work with now..

Comment: Then mark this answer as a solution to the question. If having further problems, feel free to post other questions (make sure to check the community first, to avoid asking an already existing question).